# How to fix: Sudoku solver Stack overflow problem

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking, sudoku

I'm trying to create a Sudoku solver in Java, in general I'm new to programming and to Java. I don't really know how to handle this kind of errors.
I keep getting a stack overflow error.

I tried diffrent codes for it , none of them worked but anyways here is my latest one:

```
public class Sudoku {

    private int[][] values;
    private boolean [][] writable;
    private static final int ZERO = 0;
    private static final int SIZE = 9;

    //just a normal constructor that sets which values are changeable and which aren't. only values equal to zero are changeable.
    public Sudoku(int[][] values) {
        this.values = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        for(int row = 0; row< SIZE ; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col< SIZE; col++)
            {
                this.values[row][col] = values[row][col];
            }
        }

         writable = new boolean[values.length][values[1].length];
         for(int i = 0;i < writable.length;i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j<writable[1].length;j++)
             {
                 if(values[i][j] == ZERO)
                 {
                     writable[i][j] = true;
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    public void setValues(int row,int col ,int value) //changes the value if the value was changeable.
    {
        if(writable[row][col])
        {
            values[row][col]= value;
        }

    }

    public int getValue(int row,int col) {
        return values[row][col];
    }

    public boolean isWritable(int row,int col)
    {
        return writable[row][col];
    }
    private boolean ConflictAtRow(int row , int num)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < SIZE;i++)
            if(getValue(row,i) == num)
                return true;
            return false;
    }
    private boolean ConflictAtCol(int col, int num)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;i++)
            if(getValue(i,col) == num)
                return true;
            return false;
    }
    private boolean ConflictAtBox(int row, int col, int num)
    {
        int r = row - row %3;
        int c = col - col %3;

        for(int i = r;i<r+3;i++)
        {
            for(int j = c;j<c+3;j++)
            {
                if(getValue(i, j) == num && row != i && col != j)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean ConflictAt(int row, int col, int num)
    {
        return ConflictAtBox(row, col, num) && ConflictAtCol(col,num) && ConflictAtRow(row, num);  //line 108
    }

    public boolean solve(int row,int col) 
    {
        int nextRow = (col < 8) ? row:row+1;
        int nextCol = (col +1)%9;
        for (row = nextRow; row < SIZE; row++) {
            for (col = NextCol; col < SIZE; col++) {
                if(isWritable(row,col))
                {
                    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
                        if(!ConflictAt(row,col,num)) //line 118
                        {
                            setValues(row,col,num);

                         if(solve(nextRow,nextCol)) //line 122
                             return true;
                         }
                             setValues(row,col,ZERO);

                    }
                }return !ConflictAt(row,col,getValue(row,col)) && 
                  solve(nextRow,nextCol);;

            }

        }return true;
    }
```

and when I run the solve() method I get the stack overflow error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.ConflictAt(Sudoku.java:108) 
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:118) 
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:122) 
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:122) 
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:122) 
    at Sudoku.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:122)
```

and so on ......

Comment: From a brief look, I am somewhat puzzled. As the Sudoku board has `9*9=81` cells, the recursion depth should be limited by `81`; have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I debug I didn't learn debugging yet but I'll check it out.

Comment: From a superficial inspection the implementation looks okay; I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: it also seems that if the puzzle was unsolvable , the method return false. and terminate successfully .

Comment: Perhaps you mean _terminate_ successfully.

Comment: yup sorry typo haha

Answer (score 0):

Once the control enters the `solve()` method for the first time, and if all the `if` conditions evaluate to `true` up to line 122, you are calling the `solve()` method again.

The problem is, every time the control hits this method, it is as though it were executing it for the first time. Because there is no change in conditions (`for` loops always start at `0`).

What this means is, the `solve()` method gets repeatedly called until the stack runs out of memory.

Comment: ok thanks, I tried editing the solve method so it wouldn't just repeat calling the same loops. still I get the same problem. I added the changed code to the post.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't compile. `row` and `col` are already declared as method parameters, and you are trying to re-declare them as for loop iterators. Besides, your for loops still start from index `0` every time `solve(..)` is called.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing the code, when I posted the comment my bad, anyway hmm.. It does compile and work now , in a strange way , it took like a minute to show any results and it shows wrong results. haha